# How can exe run in qemu system mode

Tags: qemu

I am trying to run exe file on qemu in system mode. For that, I created a compiled a kernel, buildroot and qemu based on the [Prepare the environment for developing Linux kernel with qemu](https://medium.com/@daeseok.youn/prepare-the-environment-for-developing-linux-kernel-with-qemu-c55e37ba8ade#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjNmMzMyYjNlOWI5MjhiZmU1MWJjZjRmOGRhNTQzY2M0YmQ5ZDQ3MjQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJuYmYiOjE1OTk4ODk2NjEsImF1ZCI6IjIxNjI5NjAzNTgzNC1rMWs2cWUwNjBzMnRwMmEyamFtNGxqZGNtczAwc3R0Zy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IjEwNzIwNjE3OTQ2ODUwNzY1NjA0MSIsImVtYWlsIjoieWVodWRhaHNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImF6cCI6IjIxNjI5NjAzNTgzNC1rMWs2cWUwNjBzMnRwMmEyamFtNGxqZGNtczAwc3R0Zy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsIm5hbWUiOiLXmdeU15XXk9eUINep16TXmdeo15AiLCJwaWN0dXJlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9saDMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tL2EtL0FPaDE0R2hNT0djVEdxSjZISzFwMFFwbzVFQTNMQmlrdENUemxwWEJLX09pZnc9czk2LWMiLCJnaXZlbl9uYW1lIjoi15nXlNeV15PXlCIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoi16nXpNeZ16jXkCIsImlhdCI6MTU5OTg4OTk2MSwiZXhwIjoxNTk5ODkzNTYxLCJqdGkiOiJmNmEwMTRlYTM5MGUwNGM3YTI0NWE0OTAzNzdiNDc1NTI0NmYwMDI5In0.ohzxVFKN45OMQsddtnDrCroj5jRtuorrk4Q4mhih0VanFqPVifoDauYdffzvTYLcCGrjmpdj9gJ-cLaJowaoN1PHefimkzzC4uknGrv0rD8g3rujCdd98V1dlVWf9N44SF6w1hWy-Gwrm8-tKNAPpthp6LdmpZKyoLvoykZ3hxNw4Pzu_iruHngxmklJ3huaaUY-cBjMqZq3pJDdpouLCzJoeRnWhth6YSdLAzS1mw5kG0VpL2HeGDBfwQDtUNIiSpNCYImOnPV61tQ7xK8vUnJBvutCikzuR4ixXiiHamw_hDpR8C1GSPnCqUAy7SabElxJ97v4uFvmCwleOQbeOw) (also created a shared folder between the host and the guest qemu from [How to share a directory with the host without networking in QEMU](https://superuser.com/questions/628169/how-to-share-a-directory-with-the-host-without-networking-in-qemu)). Now, I want to compile and run exe on the qemu system... After compiling the  [pcimem](https://github.com/billfarrow/pcimem) project on the host, I opened qemu, moved to the shared folder and tried to run it, but I got `-sh: ./pcimem: not found`. When I run `ls` in qemu, I can see the files and that they have the right permissions:

```
# ls -la
total 80
drwxrwxr-x    3 1006     1001          4096 Oct  2 17:32 .
drwxrwxr-x    3 1006     1001          4096 Oct  2 17:31 ..
drwxrwxr-x    8 1006     1001          4096 Oct  2 17:31 .git
-rw-rw-r--    1 1006     1001            59 Oct  2 17:31 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--    1 1006     1001         18092 Oct  2 17:31 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-r--    1 1006     1001            80 Oct  2 17:31 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--    1 1006     1001          5691 Oct  2 17:31 README
-rwxrwxr-x    1 1006     1001         21672 Oct  2 17:32 pcimem
-rw-rw-r--    1 1006     1001          5283 Oct  2 17:31 pcimem.c
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I run exe on the qemu in system mode ?

**Update:**
I found out [here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/adding-Programs-to-BusyBox/td-p/665118) that I am trying to invoke the exe file from busybox terminal, and apparently it can't be done... so I tried to invoke the next command line:

```
ash ./pcimem
```

but than I get the next error:

```
./pcimem: line 1: can't create @: Operation not permitted
./pcimem: line 1:ELF: not found
./pcimem: line 2: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

Comment: Please include the command you're using to invoke `pcimem` (i.e. How are you trying to run it?)

Comment: @rfmodulator - no matter how I am trying to invoke pcimem, it always return the "not found" error... it is like the file is not exists (although it is there....)

Comment: Change to the directory, type `./pcimem`, press enter and post the output.

Comment: "ash ./pcimem" is trying to run your ELF executable as a shell script. It's not a shell script, which is why the shell prints those errors. Don't try to run it like that.